# Closing streaming jdbc ResultSet before reading everything on MySQL 5.6.x

Tags: mysql, jdbc, resultset

Is it possible to close `ResultSet` after reading only a few rows? Sometimes I have to issue a query that would return 10mil rows even though later in the code I'll know that I don't need 10mil just 20, or 50, or 1000..

I have this code which creates streaming `ResultSet` but it freezes on `rs.close()` - I guess from trying to read remaining rows. So instead of finishing in few milliseconds it hangs up for minutes...

```
    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from users",
            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));
        break;
    }
    rs.close();
    con.close();
```

Comment: replacing `rs.close(); con.close();` with `con.abort(...)` is the only option for real?

Comment: As far as I know, this is the result of limitations in the MySQL protocol.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Bugs: #95763: can not closed streaming result set](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95763)

According to the response of MySQL Verification Team, this is how the MySQL protocol works.

But Mark Matthews provided an alternative way:

> The only option for clients if they don't want to wait, is to close the connection to MySQL.